# Scala - Delete between defined region

Tags: scala

I Have a series of tests that need to pass one of them includes deleting the buffer between the defined region (which is between the marker and cursor) and inserting the cut text in the paste. I then need to set the cursor and marker to the beginning of the cut text (see below code for a better understanding)

```
class Buffer(s: String) {
  import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
  import scala.io.StdIn


  private var buffer: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s)
  private var cursor: Int = 0  // cursor is in between characters
  private var marker: Int = 0  // marker is in between characters
  private var paste: String = ""
  private def end: Int = buffer.length              // the end of the line
  private def lwr: Int = Math.min(marker, cursor)
  private def upr: Int = Math.max(marker, cursor)

   /*
    * Accessor methods to return aspects of the state
    */

  def getCursor: Int = cursor
  def getMarker: Int = marker
  def getString: String = buffer.toString
  def getPaste: String = paste
```

- Delete the contents of the defined region and save the cut string in the paste
- buffer. This operation re-sets the cursor and the marker to the start of the
- cut text. For example:
- B U F F E R      marker = 1
- ^     ^         cursor = 4
- Then perform  xd()
- B E R           marker = 1
- ^              cursor = 1
  */

I have written some code:

```scala
def xd() {
    paste = buffer.substring(lwr, upr)
    buffer = buffer.delete(lwr, upr)
    cursor = end
    marker = end
}
```

this seems to pass the other tests but does not set the marker and cursor.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: how do you set cursor and marker?

Comment: At first you say "set the cursor and marker to the beginning of the cut text" and the you say "does not set the marker and cursor to the end of the string". So do you want to set them to the beginning or to the end?

Comment: The marker and cursor need to be set at the beginning of the cut text.

Answer (score 1):

First in *Scala* you would try to have no mutable state (`var`).

Here is a solution for *cut and paste* that is immutable:

```
  case class Buffer(s: String, paste: String, private val cursor: Int = 0, private val marker: Int = 0) {

    def mark(str: String): Buffer = {
      val startIndex = s.indexOf(str)
      val endIndex = startIndex + str.length
      Buffer(s, startIndex, endIndex)
    }

    def cut(): Buffer = {
      Buffer(s.take(cursor) + s.drop(marker), // rest of the String
         s.take(marker).drop(cursor))         // paste of the String
    }
  }
```

You can use it like this:

```
Buffer("hello there")   // > Buffer(hello there,,0,0)
  .mark("o t")          // > Buffer(hello there,,4,7)
  .cut()                // > Buffer(hellhere,o t,0,0)
```

You see the result of each line.

Let me know if you need more support or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Thank you I will try and implement this